# I change one variable then i equals it to 2nd variable.When i change 1st variable, second variable is changes automatically

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I have a variable.Then i assign variable to 2nd variable. When i change 2nd variable 1st variable is changed automatically. But i want to change 2nd variable only.

```py
a={'a':1, 'b':2}
b=a

b.update({'x':78})

print(a,'\n===========================\n', b)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you are not creating a copy, but a reference.

Use the dictionaries `.copy()` method method to get a copy

```py
a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
b = a.copy()
```

Comment: thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, you did a reference and not a copy. In your case `a` and `b` have the same address in memory. Hence, update `a` or `b` is the same.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) an explanation about the difference between these two concepts.